# Http server - slow read

Tags: apache, denial-of-service

I am trying to simulate a slow http read attack against apache server running on my localhost.
But it seems like, the server does not complain and simply waits forever for the client to read.

This is what I do:

1. Request a huge file (say ~1MB) from the http server
2. Read the response from the server in a loop waiting 100 secs before successive reads

Since the file is huge and the client receive buffer is small, the server has to send the file in multiple chunks. But, at the client side, I wait for 100 secs between successive reads. As a result, the server often polls the client and finds that, the receive window size of the client is zero since the client has not yet read the receive buffer.

But it looks like the server does not bother to break the connection and it silently keeps polling the client. Server sends the data when the client window size is > 0 and again goes back to wait for the client.

I want to know whether there are any apache config parameters that I can set to break the connection from the server side after waiting sometime for the client to read the data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would be more useful to you, (simpler and saves you time): http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/ which is a Perl script that sends partial HTTP requests, the Apache server leaves the connection open (now unavailable to new users) and if executed on a Linux environment, (Linux does not limit threads beyond hardware capability) you can effectively block all open sockets, and in turn prevent other users from accessing the server. It uses minimal bandwidth because it does not "flood" the server with requests, it simply slowly takes the sockets hostage. You can download the file here: http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/slowloris.pl

To prevent an attack like this (well, mitigate) see here: https://serverfault.com/questions/32361/how-to-best-defend-against-a-slowloris-dos-attack-against-an-apache-web-server

You could also use a load-balancer or round-robin setup.

Comment: Thanks @mesh. I have seen this attack but I am specifically looking at the attack that I described. Let me know if you know the server config option to reset the connection.

Comment: @sachin2182 - Not sure if this will work for your purposes, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout where in httpd.conf or the .htaccess you put `TimeOut xyz` where xyz is the number of seconds you want to wait at most before killing the connection. I recommend maybe 10 seconds if you have a fast connection.

Comment: The timeout directive is for the requests sent by the client. Suppose if the server did not receive the request (that it expects) from the client for certain time, then if we want to break the connection, then this option can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[slowhttptest](https://code.google.com/p/slowhttptest/wiki/SlowReadTest)** to test the slow read attack you're describing. (It can also be used to test slow sending of headers.)